# unable to download pkg file placed in web using curl

Tags: macos, pkg-file

I uploaded a pkg file and placed it in a portal. Using curl -O "path to pkg". I am unable to download , i am getting an html document, instead of pkg file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By mistake i added /var/www/html to the path of pkg. This need not be mentioned while downloading using curl -o command. Only if we wanted to go to that particular location we need to mention this path in commandline.